# Design connectivity of qasm_simulator

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

About the `qasm_simulator`, does it have on its 32 qubits a qubit connectivity design like as `ibmq_16_melbourne` or as another real device of IBM Experience and Qiskit?

Comment: On IBM Q simulator each qubit is connected to each other.

Answer (score 3):

There is no qubit connectivity map for the simulator, all qubits are connected to each other to enable you to simulate any 32 qubit program.

Answer (score 2):

You can control the connectivity using parameters of the `execute` function. You can obtain the connectivity of a specific device by querying the backend configuration, and pass it to `execute`. The execution starts with a transpilation step, that modifies the circuit into an equivalent circuit which is valid with the given connectivity. Then the modified circuit is passed to the simulator. The simulator itself is not aware of the connectivity.